# How to Compact geodatabases in multiple directories using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase

I am trying to write a script to walk through all folders in my workspace and find and compact all geodatabases in my workspace.  I feel like I'm on the right track but I am stuck.

```
import acrpy, os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace "C:"

for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(arcpy.env.workspace)
    for file in files
        if ".gdb" in file:
        workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB")
            for workspace in workspaces:
            arcpy.Compact_management(workspace)
```

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  If it is 10.1 SP1 or later then arcpy.da.Walk becomes available.

Comment: I am using 10.2.2

Comment: question updated to include release version

Comment: Where are you stuck?  If you are getting an error message then include that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

First, a file geodatabase is a directory, not a file, so you'll want to iterate over the directories, not the files. Second, `arcpy.ListWorkspaces` lists workspaces in the current directory, not the directory you are iterating over in your loop. Also, it is unnecessary as the arcpy.Compact_management will accept paths as string. (It does weed out any possible directories with ".gdb" in the that might not be geodatabases.) Finally, pay attention to your indenting, as this is very important to the python interpreter to separate blocks of code. Always indent after a colon (:) Try the following:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/"

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(arcpy.env.workspace):
    for dir in dirs:
        if ".gdb" in dir:
            workspace = print os.path.join(path, dir)
            arcpy.Compact_management(workspace)
```

To test, you could substitute `print workspace` for the call to `arcpy.Compact_management`, just to make sure you are hitting all the geodatabases you expect.

Comment: Thanks Arnold.  I got a syntax answer but got it working by inserting 
workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB") on line 9.

thanks for your help!

Comment: @kejad could you tell the changes you have made to the code. Exactly showing the same syntax error for me.

Comment: OK. As you have mentioned i've inserted workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB"). But that will list only the gdb's in the current directory. In the original code provided by Arnold, workspace = print os.path..print has to be removed.